# React testing state of component with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple component where you click a button and it uses fetch to call an API and log the result:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isLoading: false};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    return fetch('https://api.github.com/users/londonappdev')
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({isLoading: false})
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to test that `isLoading` is set to `true` while the request is in progress and then is set to `false` once the request is complete.

My test looks like this:

```
it('sets isloading to true while loading', () => {
  global.fetch = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({
    ok: true,
    json: () => Promise.resolve({'user': 'test'})
  }));

  const c = shallow(<App />);
  c.instance().handleClick().then(() => {
    expect(c.instance().state.isLoading).toEqual(false);
  });
  expect(c.instance().state.isLoading).toEqual(true);
});
```

This works, however my question is: Is it safe/reliable to test state this way? Since `setState` is asynchronous, is it possible that `expect(c.instance().state.isLoading).toEqual(true);` would be called before the state is properly set?

Any advice on the best way to test this type of component would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that's perfectly safe. Similarly to `setTimeout(callback, 0)`, promise callbacks are queued to run after the rest of the synchronous code. This ensures your assertions will run at the correct points in your program.

Small tip for unit testing - instead of calling `c.instance().handleClick()` I would call `c.find('button').prop('onClick')()`. Your component is the "unit" that you're testing and so you should try to avoid accessing internal methods / properties

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Would you still recommend simulating the button click even if this is a container and the button/form will appear on a sub component?

Comment: If I was trying to test this App component and the button is in a sub component then I wouldn’t care about the button anymore - I would test that the state updates when the function prop that I pass to the SubComponent is called. Eg if your subcomponent looks like this: function SubComponent ({ handler}) { return <button onClick={handler}>click me!</button>; }  then I would  call it with c.find(‘SubComponent’).prop(‘handler’)()